# Grep: Count the number of times a string occurs if another string does not occur

Tags: grep

I have a set of many `.json.gz` files. In each file, there are entries such as this:

```
{"type":"e1","public":true, "login":"username1", "org":{"dict","of":"lots_of_things"}}
{"type":"e2","public":true, "login":"username2"}
```

No matter where in each nested dict "login" appears, I want to be able to detect it and take the username, only if the key "org" does not exist anywhere in the nested dict. I also want to count the number of times each username appears in the files.

My final output should be a file of dicts that looks like this:

```
{'username2: 1}
```

because of course username1 wouldn't be counted: the key "org" appears in its dict.

I'm looking for something like:

```
zgrep -Rv "org" . | zgrep -o 'login":"[^"]*"' /path/to/files/* | cut -d'"' -f3 | sort | uniq -c | sed '1i{
       s/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*\(.*\)/"\2": \1,/;$a}' > outputfile.txt
```

I'm not sure about this part:

```
zgrep -Rv "org" . |
```

The rest successfully creates the type of file I'm looking for. I'm just unsure about the order of operations here.

EDIT

I should have been more clear, I apologize. There are also often multiple instances of the key "login" per main dict object. For example (using "k" for any key that is not login and not org, and using "v" for a value):

```
{"k":"v","k":{"k":{"k":"v","login":"username1"},"k":"v"},"k":{"k":"v","login":"username2"}}
{"k":{"k":"v","k":"v"},"k":{"org":{"k":"v","k":v,"login":"username3"},"k":"v"},"k":{"k":"v","login":"username4"}}
{"k":{"k":"v"},"k":{"k":{"k":"v","login":"username1"},"login":"username2"}}
```

Since the key `org` appears in the second dict, I want to exclude usernames 3 and 4 from the dict I make and save to a file.

For example, I want this in a file:

```
{'username1': 2}
{'username2': 2}
```

Comment: Did you try parsing the JSON with a syntax aware parser like `jq`? Also can you provide a valid JSON sample, so that I can recommend a way to use `jq` for it

Comment: The thing is, they aren't really valid json files from what I understand. The format is as I gave it. To be valid json, I think I can't have nested dicts, but that's what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
zgrep -v "org" *.json.gz | zgrep -o 'login":"[^"]*"' | cut -d'"' -f3 | sort | uniq -c | sed '1i{
       s/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*\(.*\)/"\2": \1,/;$a}' > usernames_2011.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

not grep but gnu sed job with script, your data in 'a'

```
i=
for e in $(sed -nE '/.*\borg\b.*/!s/.*"login":"(\w+)".*/{\1:}/p' a)
{
let i++;echo ${e/:/:$i}
}
```

use '>' at end to save in file

if better regex : 'pcregrep' installed, it does as well;

```
pcregrep -io '(?!.*\borg\b.*)(?<="login":")\w+(?=".*)' a
```

replace sed...  script above, with a bit adjusted printout

Answer (score 0):

AWK solution and replacing find -R with more reliable find:

```
find . -type f -name "*.json.gz" -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -v -h '"org"' | awk '{ if ( match($0,/"login":"[^"]+"/) ) logins[substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8)]++; } END { for ( i in logins ) print("{" i ":" logins[i] "}"); }'
```

Example output:

```
{"username2":1}
```